# Prevent ' from being entered into textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Would someone be able to help me with some javascript code please that will alert on submission of a form if there's a ' character (apostrophe) within a textbox?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us some code that you tried..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add keyUp event listener to the textbox. Check the keyCode of the key pressed. If it matched for keyCode of `'`, alert the user. After that, replace the `'` with a blank.

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 222){ // check if the key pressed is '
    alert('No Single Quotes Please!');
    this.value = this.value.replace("'", "");  // replace ' with a blank
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Readup on these:

- [`.addEventListener | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)
- [`event.keyCode | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.keyCode)
- [`.replace() | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.indexOf` to check for apostrophe's presence:

```
var str = "That's awesome";
if(str.indexOf("'") !== -1) {
    alert("no apostrophe's allowed");
}
```

Doing it on form submission is a separate issue.